# IntelliJ dialog focus

Tags: webstorm, android-studio-3.0

Trying to control Android Studio by keyboard only, I do not know why, but when I focus "Cancel" button and press enter, it acts like I clicked on the default button (next tip is shown). The same scenario applies to WebStorm.

[image]

then I press Tab or right arrow (**notice the blue glow around the button**)
[image]

Comment: Try pressing `Space` here. I believe it's something to do with Java Swing used here (default behaviour) -- see this comment for example: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-14355#comment=27-59418 . Or maybe it's just https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-174374 of the similar/related ticket....

Comment: Works well, thanks. But it still looks like a strange behavior to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, as LazyOne mentioned, is to use **SPACE** instead of ENTER.